# Separate hook from component and then import hook to component

Tags: reactjs

So I finally took the deep dive into hooks.  Yes, now I get how easy they can be to use.  However, I know one of the most important aspects of it is reusable logic.  To share the hook between components, and make my functional component(container now?) even cleaner, how would I separate this?  I understand that I can create a custom hook, as long as it starts with use.  So for instance, I want to fetch a bunch of tickets and get the length, I have the following:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function TicketCounter() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`/ticketapi/ticketslist/`)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.data) {
                    setData(res.data)
                }
            })
    }
        , []);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {data.length}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default TicketCounter
```

What's the best way to do this?  What method are you using?  Are you storing these hooks inside your src folder?  I imagine you have a folder for hooks, with each hook having it's own js file?  Anyhoo, thanks in advance folks.  I absolutely LOVE react and all it has to offer, and am super excited about hooks (2 months after everyone else lol).

Answer (score 3):

Well I figured it out.

Sep hook file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
const useFetchAPI = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {

        axios.get(url)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.data) {
                    setData(res.data)
                }
            })
    }
        , []);


    return data;
};

export default useFetchAPI
```

and then my component(container?)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import useFetchAPI from '../hooks/TicketCounterHook'

function TicketCounter() {
    const url = `/ticketapi/ticketslist/`
    const data = useFetch(url)
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {data.length}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default TicketCounter
```